# mostrar mensaje exitoso y error en div

Tags: reactjs, api

por favor necesito ayuda con esto, mas que todo, para resumir necesito mostrar en la parte del render return en el jsx. en un div.resultado la respuesta de EXITOSO Y ERROR. como veran ahora solo me muestra en la consola, quiero mostrarlo en un div, he buscado un poco de info y me dicen que debería guardar en una variable cada if y mostrar el resultado en un div como lo puse, espero quede mas claro la pregunta. probe de esta forma pero en el error me da innerHTML NULL, por que ejecuta el javascript antes que el render, o html, alguna solución. Gracias.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Checkout } from 'checkout-component-react'; // libreria externa
class ApiPagos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    window.CheckoutJS.publicKey = "0000000000000000000000"; 
    window.CheckoutJS.settings({ 
      reference: { 
        numId: 111111111, 
        codigoProducto: "1111111111111111" 
      }, 
      operation: "subscription", //or "subscription"
      currency: "PEN", 
      amount: "", 
      callback: "checkoutRpta", 
      name: "",
      lastName:"",
      email: "", 
      runtime: "node", 
      subscription: true, 
      //imgLoading: "RUTA_COMPLETA_IMAGEN", 
      htmlLoading: "<p><span class='mensaje'>Suscripcion realizada exitosamente</span><i>icono</i></p>", 
      cssLoadingProcess: "spinner",
      attributes: ["required", ""],
    }); 
    window.checkoutRpta = this.checkoutRpta; 
  }

  checkoutRpta(response) { 
    console.log("RESPUESTA => "); 
    if (response.data) { 
      console.log("EXITOSO"); 
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      var success = (JSON.stringify(response.data));
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = success;

    } 
    if (response.error) { 
      console.error("ERROR"); 
      console.error(JSON.stringify(response.error));
      var fallado = (JSON.stringify(response.error));
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = fallado;
    }
  }
render() {
    return (
          <div className="pagos">
                  
                  <div id="resultado"></div>
            
            <Checkout type="button" className="button btn-red btn-normal pull-right btn-continue" /> 
          </div>      
    );
  }
}
export default ApiPagos;
```

[image: respuesta]

Comment: cuando y donde ejecutas `checkoutRpta` ? Parece que no lo ejecutas en el componente sino de algun sitio externo

Comment: al dar click en el type="button" Button

Comment: si en realidad es un api externa, que me trae esa respuestas puse una imagen que es lo que devuelve. necesito capturar ese mesaje de exitoso o error en un div.

Comment: ya pero el click que comentas no lo veo en el componente. Está en otro componente?

Comment: el <Checkout type="button" className="button btn-red btn-normal pull-right btn-continue" /> esta realizando una accion de acuerdo a este parámetro operation: "subscription", //or "subscription", es una checkout externo, si le cambio a payment es pagos, ahora subscribe, eso ya esta delcarado  asi internamente. solo quiero capturar el resultados de las respuestas que me muestra en consola.

Comment: alguna idea, por favor, normalmente, lo que siempre piden es poder capturar los mensajes de error y exitoso que devuelve los servicios. los servicios siempre nos da un código  y lo tratamos de igualar según sea el caso. if (codgo === 200) {'mesaje exitoso o error.'} eso se llama interceptores creo, donde puedo encontrar información como capturar errores a los mensajes que envía los servicios, es lo que necesito para este ejemplo y futuros siempre me lo piden.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [THIS SET STATE IS NOT A FUNTION](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350421/this-set-state-is-not-a-funtion)

Answer (score 0):

La api de checkout que usas no se como funciona pero por lo que entiendo es que el componente `ApiPagos` ya no existe en el DOM cuando se ejecuta `checkoutRpta` porque este es un callback que le pasas a la api. Y también lo estas definiendo en `windows` así que es una función global accesible en toda la app.

Puedes probar con el hook `componentWillUnmount()` para ver si `ApiPagos` sigue renderizado o se desmonta. Y así ver si la función de `checkoutRpta` se ejecuta antes de este hook o después.

Pero por lo que comentas que `document.getElementById('resultado')` esto te da `null` entiendo que ya ha sido desmontado el componente `ApiPagos`.

Puedes poner el `<div id="resultado"></div>` un componente que siempre vaya a existir como `App`.

O crearlo dinamicamente con `createElement`.

O sino mirar si esta librería de checkout tiene algún componente para react en npm.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Checkout } from 'checkout-component-react'; // libreria externa
class ApiPagos extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    window.CheckoutJS.publicKey = "0000000000000000000000"; 
    window.CheckoutJS.settings({ 
      reference: { 
        numId: 111111111, 
        codigoProducto: "1111111111111111" 
      }, 
      operation: "subscription", //or "subscription"
      currency: "PEN", 
      amount: "", 
      callback: "checkoutRpta", 
      name: "",
      lastName:"",
      email: "", 
      runtime: "node", 
      subscription: true, 
      //imgLoading: "RUTA_COMPLETA_IMAGEN", 
      htmlLoading: "<p><span class='mensaje'>Suscripcion realizada exitosamente</span><i>icono</i></p>", 
      cssLoadingProcess: "spinner",
      attributes: ["required", ""],
    }); 
    window.checkoutRpta = this.checkoutRpta; 
  }

  checkoutRpta(response) { 
    console.log("RESPUESTA => "); 
    // esta variable ahora es global porque se ha declarado en el objeto `window`
    // para acceder a esta variable donde quieras mostrar el error puedes `window.checkoutResult`
    window.checkoutResult = response;

  }
render() {
    return (
          <div className="pagos">

                  <div id="resultado"></div>

            <Checkout type="button" className="button btn-red btn-normal pull-right btn-continue" /> 
          </div>      
    );
  }
}
export default ApiPagos;
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: si, entiendo pero es mas sencillo que eso, es como cuando invocas un servicio por fetch o axios, y el resultado primero lo sacas en consola. luego le asignas una variable para pintarlo en el HTML.

Comment: el resultado ya viene en esos console. lo que necesito es almacenarlo en una variable para mostrarlo en le HTML. pero tengo problemas.

Comment: pues puedes guardar en una variable global. Cuando te llegan los datos en el callback `window.result = result` (esto no se recomienda mucho) asi ya lo tienes en una variable o si usas redux pues en el store.

Comment: me ayudaría un ejemplo, deje los códigos arriba, probé de esa forma y no me funciona, serian muy amable. Gracias

Comment: he actualizado mi respuesta espero que sirva