# THIS SET STATE IS NOT A FUNTION

Tags: reactjs

Su ayuda por favor en esta función me devuelve este error, entiendo que es algo de ES6, hay que ponerle un bind a this, algo así que podria probar. no se si tengo que poner todo el código.
Gracias.

```js
class contentOnDesktop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      codigo:'',
      mensaje: ''
    };
    
  }



checkoutRpta = (response) => {
    if (response.data) { 
      console.log("EXITOSO")
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

      var data = response.data.resultado;
          console.log(data, 'data de resultado');
          this.setState({
            mensaje: data.mensaje,
            codigo: data.codigo,
          });
    }
    if (response.error) { 
      console.error("ERROR"); 
      console.error(JSON.stringify(response.error));
    }
  }
```

```html
{ this.state.codigo === 1001 ? <div className="error"><em>{this.state.mensaje}</em></div> : '' }
              { this.state.codigo === 2001 ? <div className="success"><em>{this.state.mensaje}</em></div> : '' }
```

Comment: Prueba con añadir `this.checkoutRpta = this.checkoutRpta.bind(this)` en el constructor. O usar arrow function `checkoutRpta = () => {...}`

Comment: this.checkoutRpta = this.checkoutRpta.bind(this), esto ya probe no funciono. la otra opción no. probare.

Comment: alguna otra idea.

Comment: lo arme asi me ayudan si es correcto:

    checkoutRpta = (response) => {
        if (response.data) { 
          console.log("EXITOSO")
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

          var data = response.data.resultado;
              console.log(data, 'data de resultado');
              this.setState({
                mensaje: data.mensaje,
                codigo: data.codigo,
              });
        }
        if (response.error) { 
          console.error("ERROR"); 
          console.error(JSON.stringify(response.error));
        }
      }

Comment: Si, esta bien el código. Como consejo no pegues el código aquí, es mejor editar la pregunta y añadir el código ahí

Comment: ya checkealo, por fa

Comment: cuando se ejecuta esta función `checkoutRpta`? deberías comprobar el `this` hace referencia al componente u otro objeto. `console.log(this)`

Comment: podrias editar el codigo y ponerlo, ara entderlo, gracias

Comment: el setSate hace referencia al componente para queme muestre los datos de codigo y mensaje, en la parte del html, se entiende o te pego el código

Comment: te puse el código donde quiero mostrar los datos de código y mensaje, depende del código que me envié. pero me da el error de this.setSate is not function