# OnClick funcion y setState

Tags: reactjs, onclick

consulta es correcto pasar en un Onclick, una funcion y un boleano, en teoria funciona pero se puede optimizar la forma de invocar ambas. les dejo el ejemplo.

el boleano podria estar dentro de la misma funcion, pero la funcion esta en otro componente y la envio por props, la funcion se recibe bien pero el boleano me da error.

necesito recibir el setState por props junto con la función, que pasa props y no en el onclick del componente.

```js
// .1 primer componente
//otro componente
//funcion lo que tenga que hacer
 const submitEmision = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // aca podria estar el setState con el boleano
    this.setState({loading : true})
  }
  
 <Componente submitEmision = {(e)=>{submitEmision(e)}} />

// 2. componente otro archivo
// componente del onclick

onClick={(e) => {
this.props.submitEmision(e)
this.setState({loading : true})
 }}
 
 
 // ORIGINAL
 
 // .1 primer componente
//otro componente
//funcion lo que tenga que hacer
 const submitEmision = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // aca podria estar el setState con el boleano
    this.setState({loading : true})
  }
  
 <Componente submitEmision = {(e)=>{submitEmision(e)}} />

// 2. componente otro archivo
// componente del onclick asi no me funciona

onClick={(e) => {
this.props.submitEmision(e)
 }}
```

Comment: Tendras que mejorar tu pregunta, ya que no se entiende qué es lo que deseas hacer, ademas añade la etiqueta reactjs para obtener una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Que quieres preguntar? y en que lenguaje?

Comment: si Gracias ya coloque lo que faltaba, sorry no copie toda la idea, es react

Comment: hay varias cosillas redundantes en tu codigo, pero yo quitarias el `this.setState({loading : true})` de tu funcion `onClick`

Comment: si lo quito no funcióna el true, por que no le llega el true de la función., no lo veas que todo eso esta en un solo archivo son 2 archivos diferentes. en la función no existe, el true lo puse como ejemplo que podría ir de esa forma, pero si lo pongo así y lo quito del botón no funciona. espero se entienda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [THIS SET STATE IS NOT A FUNTION](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350421/this-set-state-is-not-a-funtion)

Answer (score 0):

A ver, si te he entendido bien, estás buscando ejecutando ejecutar desde el componente hijo el método `submitEmision`, correcto?

Para esto solamente tienes que pasar la `REFERENCIA` de la función y no su ejecución. Me explico un poco mejor por si esto suena un poco confuso.

```js
class Padre extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true
  }

  submitEmision = (e) => {
    // Ejecutas setState o la lógica que requiera "e"
  }

  render() {
    return {
      <Hijo submitEmision={this.submitEmision} /> // Solo pasas la referencia
    }
  }
}

class Hijo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return {
      <button onClick={(e) => this.props.submitEmision(e)} />
    }
  }
}
```

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo te muestra una de ejemplo a modo de que pueda dar algo más de luz a tus dudas sobre el manejo de las props y referencia a funciones.

Fíjate que en el hijo, `e` sería el evento si viene de un campo input u otro elemento del DOM. Sino requires de enviar `e` de esa forma puedes pasar desde el hijo también la referencia de ésta forma:

```js
class Hijo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return {
      <button onClick={this.props.submitEmision} />
    }
  }
}
```

En el caso de que necesites pasar al padre un valor del estado del hijo por ejemplo, lo haríamos de la siguiente forma:

```js
class Hijo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const item = "Para el mejor padre del mundo"
    return {
      <button onClick={this.props.submitEmision(item)} />
    }
  }
}
```

De esta manera pasaríamos item al padre, pero, para que funcione hay que hacer un pequeño ajuste en el método `submitEmision` del padre. Al llamar directamente la función `this.props.submitEmission` pasándle item, ésta se va a ejecutar en cada render, cosa que queremos evitar. Para ello hacemos lo siguiente en el padre:

```js
class Padre extends React.Component {
  submitEmision = (item) => () => {  // OJO AQUI AÑADIMOS UNA ARROW MAS
    console.log(item); // Para el mejor padre del mundo
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva, un abrazo